# Call Powershell Script from VBA(with Parameter)

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I want to call a Powershell-Script from Excel VBA and pass 1 Parameter. Without VBA the Script works perfectly and does what it supposed to do.. As soon as the Call works, i would like to add 1 parameter, but first the successfull call...

But i cant manage to call it within Excel VBA. First ill show you my Powershell-Script:

```
#param([string]$server)
$server = "chvmes01"

$BasicPath = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

write-host $BasicPath

Invoke-Command -FilePath $BasicPath\IISReport.ps1 -ComputerName $server

Read-Host "Return drücken..."
```

In VBA I created this Code:

```
strCommand = "Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -File """ & BasicPath & """, 1"
Set WsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WsShell.Run (strCommand)
```

strCommand looks like this:

> Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoExit -File
>   "E:\Temp\Registry\EXCEL_ALLE\Version_AllFromExcel_Aktuell\IISReport\InvokeCommand.ps1",
>   1

Like this i get the following Error:
[image]

I have no idea what i can change anymore, i read so many forum posts and changed different things, but nothing worked!

I tried with strCommand without "" like this:

```
strCommand = "Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -File " & BasicPath & ", 1"
```

I tried

```
-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted AND -ExecutionPolicy ByPass
```

I tried with and without

```
-NoExit
```

I also tried

```
Shell (strCommand)
```

As i mentioned, the Scripts work perfectly without VBA! 
Can anyone help here?

Comment: I'm not huge on powershell, but what happens when you change the #param([string]$server) to #param([$server) in the PS script?

Comment: Yes i can try this, but as the script does not execute i cant test if it works.. first we have to get the executing working...

Comment: Oh sorry. I misinterpreted it.

Comment: No worries, thanks anyway!

Comment: Why is there a `", 1"` in the end?

Comment: Its for the WindowStyle, the 1 stands for vbNormalFocus --> Window has focus and is restored to its original size and position.

Comment: but shouldn't it be `WsShell.Run (strCommand, 1)` then? And remove it from the `strCommand`?

Comment: i found the solution, check my answer, you led me to the answer! thanks a lot..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the Solution!!

Actually the comment from @Pᴇʜ lead me to the answer!

I i mixed up the

```
Set WsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WsShell.Run (strCommand)
```

with

```
Shell (strCommand)
```

The ", 1" is only for the Shell Command.

I only had to change my strCommand to

```
    strCommand = "Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -File " & BasicPath
    Set WsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WsShell.Run (strCommand)
```

and its working!

Now i can try to pass the parameter to powershell! Thanks a lot!

Comment: was just about to post it. `WsShell.Run (strCommand, 1)` should be correct.

Comment: Close... But the 1 is not needed at all, one only needs it For the Shell command.. i mixed it up a little, thats why it was not working ;) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function

Comment: But WsShell has a window style too: `WshShell.Run strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn]` eg `0` for hidden and `1` for normal focus … there are some more.

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to indicate that a comma is being appended on to the end of your path. You likely just need to wrap it in single quotes. Try this:

```
strCommand = "Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -File '" & BasicPath & "'"
```

Comment: I tried this, but now the error Text is:
Processing -File ' 'E:\Temp\Registry\',' failed: The given path's format is not supported. Specify a valid path for the -File parameter. Whats wrong with this path??

Comment: Are you certain that the way you're building the `BasicPath` variable in VBA is still working?

Comment: ^ The reason its saying that the above path is not supported by the way is just because its not currently pointing to a `.ps1` file. So yeah, check that `BasicPath` still has the full path the file. You haven't shared that in your question so it's hard for me to say but that's my guess.

Comment: BasicPath looks like this "E:\Temp\Registry\EXCEL_ALLE\Version_AllFromExcel_Aktuell\IISReport\InvokeCommand.ps1" i dont know what should be wrong about this..

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer. Scripts were disabled, so I ran the file with ExecutionPolicy Bypass

Comment: This question was already solved and the OP has self answered and accepted it.